# Determining Ion from Emission Spectrum

Tags: atomic-physics

Consider an ion that has had all its electrons stripped from it except for one. This series produces spectral lines as described by the Bohr model and corresponds to electronic transitions that terminate in the same final state.

The longest wavelength produced is $112.5 nm$ and the shortest is $40.5nm$. What is the ion?

From this information I gathered that the lowest energy released is $~11.043 eV$ and the highest is $30.676eV$. Since the highest energy released would be from a very high state to the ground state $(\infty \rightarrow 1)$, then:

$$30.676 eV = 13.6eV \cdot \frac{z^2}{1^2}$$

However, this gives me $z=1.5$, which is an impossible result. Where did my logic go wrong?

Comment: Is this supposed to only be one possible series?  As such, is the assumption that $n=1$ for the lowest state valid?

Comment: The shortest wavelength seems to be from an $n=2$ to $n=1$ transition. I do not see why there would be a longest wavelength.

Comment: Yes it's supposed to be only one possible series. How would the shortest wavelength be from $n=2$ to $n=1$? Wouldn't, for example, $n=3$ to $n=1$ release more energy?

Comment: BowlOfRed is right, disregard my comment. The series limit is given.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the bohr model is thoroughly discredited. Electrons aren't orbiting beads.

Answer (score 1):

> The longest wavelength produced is $112.5 nm$ and the shortest is $40.5nm$. What is the ion?
> From this information I gathered that the lowest energy released is $~11.043 eV$ and the highest is $30.676eV$. Since the highest energy released would be from a very high state to the ground state $(\infty \rightarrow 1)$, then:
> $$30.676 eV = 13.6eV \cdot \frac{z^2}{1^2}$$

> However, this gives me $z=1.5$, which is an impossible result. Where did my logic go wrong?

The [Rydberg formula for a hydrogenic atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series) reads:
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda} = Z^2 R_\infty \left({\frac{1}{n_I^2} - \frac{1}{n^2}}\right)\;,
$$
where $n_I$ is the initial un-filled orbital quantum number (the lower energy orbital), $n>n_I$ is the orbital from which the electron will "drop down" to fill the lower orbital, $Z$ is the atomic number, and $R_\infty$ is $1.09677\times 10^7$ inverse meters.

Inverting and converting units gives an expression for the wavelength in nanometers:
$$
\lambda = \frac{91.16}{Z^2}\frac{n_I^2 n^2}{n^2 - n_I^2}\tag{nano-meters}
$$

It is easier to search for the shortest wavelength first, since we can simplify a lot by sending $n$ to $\infty$. This leads to:
$$
\lambda_{shortest} = \frac{91.16}{Z^2}n_I^2\tag{nano-meters}\;,
$$
where we know that $\lambda_{shortest}=40.5$nm, so we can also write this as:
$$
0.444 = \frac{n_I^2}{Z^2}\;.
$$

Now we just need to try and find **integers** $n_I$ and $Z$ that could satisfy this equation. For example, $n_I=1$ will *not* work since it can only give a LHS that is either 1 (Z=1), or 0.25 (Z=2), or lower. Searching a parameter space of integers between, say, 1 and 10 means we have to do 100 different calculations. It is easiest to do so many calculations with the help of a computer. It turns out that $n_I=4$ and $Z=6$ provides one solution since
$$
4^2/6^2 = 0.444\;.
$$

Of course, if we only look at the shortest wavelength, there are many other possible solutions. (For example, $n_I=8$ and $Z=12$ is also a solution.) But we also know that the longest wavelength has to be $112.5$nm.
$$
\lambda_{longest} = \frac{91.16}{Z^2}\frac{n_I^2(n_I+1)^2}{2n_I + 1}\tag{nano-meters}\;,
$$
which is only consistent with the $n_I=4$ and $Z=6$ solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the line at 40.5 nm may not terminate at n=1 - or the question is incorrect. because the n=2 to n=1 line for He$^+$ is at 30.4 nm - although this has an energy of about 40.8 eV if I remember correctly, which makes me wonder if 40.5nm should be 40.5 eV....

I don't want to say more, I don't know the answer and I won't work it out, but I agree that a transition to n=1 gives a non-integer z value even if you try n=2 to n=1.

Comment: I got that $n=5$ to $n=2$ for  $z=2$ works fairly well for the 112.5 nm line, although that was through an educated guess. Therefore since they end at the same final state, the 40.5 nm would be $n=\infty$ to $n=2$, but that gives me $z=3.3$.  Am I right to assume that there exist some z and some transition where z is the same?

Comment: @BrydenC z has to be the same for both lines - maybe n>2 ... if i was doing this I might set up an excel spreadsheet or something to try to search for upper and lower values of n

Comment: @BrydenC - you might need to set up simultaneous equations... with data from the two lines...

Comment: I'm convinced the calculation shouldn't  be this intricate. I'm sure it's supposed  to be simpler and maybe I'm misunderstanding it.

Answer (score 0):

$Z=6$ for the atomic number and $n=4$ for the lowest term of the series seem to work fine.